# Seeing /priv/static files in Phoenix via Heroku

Tags: heroku, elixir, image-uploading, phoenix-framework

I just created a simple image uploading app with Phoenix using [arc](https://medium.com/@Stephanbv/elixir-phoenix-uploading-images-locally-with-arc-b1d5ec88f7a).  Works well on my local.

I pushed the app to heroku and tried uploading an image.  On the index.html (where I should see the image) I see a broken image icon with `<img src="/priv/static/images/myimage.jpg">`.  Ok, so I need to trim away the `/priv/static`, but if I try to visit the image itself at `https://my-app-12345.herokuapp.com/images/myimage.jpg` I don't see anything.

Is there a `heroku run ls` command or something that I can do that tells me if I can see if the image is at least uploaded?

Comment: Try `heroku run find .`. That should list all the files present recursively.

Comment: You can also try `heroku run bash` to explore interactively.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all the files by running the `find .` command. You can run the command on Heroku directly with `heroku run find .` or start a shell like `sh` or `bash` on Heroku with `heroku run sh` or `heroku run bash` and then type `find .`.